# i want to switch some code from code pen to visual studio code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner and wanted to add one button that I saw on YouTube, the author left a link to the codepen, I went in and copied all the code from there, and pasted it into my project in visual studio code, but the html code looked strange and didn't work at all.
[Link to the Codepen page][1]

```js
$('.order').click(function(e) {

    let button = $(this);

    if(!button.hasClass('animate')) {
        button.addClass('animate');
        setTimeout(() => {
            button.removeClass('animate');
        }, 10000);
    }

});
```

```css
:root {
    --primary: #275EFE;
    --primary-light: #7699FF;
    --dark: #1C212E;
    --grey-dark: #3F4656;
    --grey: #6C7486;
    --grey-light: #CDD9ED;
    --white: #FFF;
    --green: #16BF78;
    --sand: #DCB773;
    --sand-light: #EDD9A9;
}

.order {
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    background: var(--dark);
    position: relative;
    height: 63px;
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 32px;
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform .3s ease;
    span {
        --o: 1;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        top: 19px;
        line-height: 24px;
        color: var(--white);
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 500;
        opacity: var(--o);
        transition: opacity .3s ease;
        &.default {
            transition-delay: .3s;
        }
        &.success {
            --offset: 16px;
            --o: 0;
            svg {
                width: 12px;
                height: 10px;
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: top;
                fill: none;
                margin: 7px 0 0 4px;
                stroke: var(--green);
                stroke-width: 2;
                stroke-linecap: round;
                stroke-linejoin: round;
                stroke-dasharray: 16px;
                stroke-dashoffset: var(--offset);
                transition: stroke-dashoffset .3s ease;
            }
        }
    }
    &:active {
        transform: scale(.96);
    }
    .lines {
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        height: 3px;
        background: var(--white);
        border-radius: 2px;
        width: 6px;
        top: 30px;
        left: 100%;
        box-shadow: 15px 0 0 var(--white), 30px 0 0 var(--white), 45px 0 0 var(--white), 60px 0 0 var(--white), 75px 0 0 var(--white), 90px 0 0 var(--white), 105px 0 0 var(--white), 120px 0 0 var(--white), 135px 0 0 var(--white), 150px 0 0 var(--white), 165px 0 0 var(--white), 180px 0 0 var(--white), 195px 0 0 var(--white), 210px 0 0 var(--white), 225px 0 0 var(--white), 240px 0 0 var(--white), 255px 0 0 var(--white), 270px 0 0 var(--white), 285px 0 0 var(--white), 300px 0 0 var(--white), 315px 0 0 var(--white), 330px 0 0 var(--white);
    }
    .back,
    .box {
        --start: var(--white);
        --stop: var(--grey-light);
        border-radius: 2px;
        background: linear-gradient(var(--start), var(--stop));
        position: absolute;
    }
    .truck {
        width: 60px;
        height: 41px;
        left: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 11px;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translateX(24px);
        &:before,
        &:after {
            --r: -90deg;
            content: '';
            height: 2px;
            width: 20px;
            right: 58px;
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            background: var(--white);
            border-radius: 1px;
            transform-origin: 100% 50%;
            transform: rotate(var(--r));
        }
        &:before {
            top: 4px;
        }
        &:after {
            --r: 90deg;
            bottom: 4px;
        }
        .back {
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 60px;
            height: 41px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .front {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 2px 9px 9px 2px;
            width: 26px;
            height: 41px;
            left: 60px;
            &:before,
            &:after {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
            }
            &:before {
                height: 13px;
                width: 2px;
                left: 0;
                top: 14px;
                background: linear-gradient(var(--grey), var(--grey-dark));
            }
            &:after {
                border-radius: 2px 9px 9px 2px;
                background: var(--primary);
                width: 24px;
                height: 41px;
                right: 0;
            }
            .window {
                overflow: hidden;
                border-radius: 2px 8px 8px 2px;
                background: var(--primary-light);
                transform: perspective(4px) rotateY(3deg);
                width: 22px;
                height: 41px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 2px;
                top: 0;
                z-index: 1;
                transform-origin: 0 50%;
                &:before,
                &:after {
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 0;
                }
                &:before {
                    top: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                    width: 14px;
                    background: var(--dark);
                }
                &:after {
                    width: 14px;
                    top: 7px;
                    height: 4px;
                    position: absolute;
                    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .14);
                    transform: skewY(14deg);
                    box-shadow: 0 7px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .14);
                }
            }
        }
        .light {
            width: 3px;
            height: 8px;
            left: 83px;
            transform-origin: 100% 50%;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 2px;
            transform: scaleX(.8);
            background: rgba(240, 220, 95, 1);
            &:before {
                content: '';
                height: 4px;
                width: 7px;
                opacity: 0;
                transform: perspective(2px) rotateY(-15deg) scaleX(.94);
                position: absolute;
                transform-origin: 0 50%;
                left: 3px;
                top: 50%;
                margin-top: -2px;
                background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(240, 220, 95, 1), rgba(240, 220, 95, .7), rgba(240, 220, 95, 0));
            }
            &.top {
                top: 4px;
            }
            &.bottom {
                bottom: 4px;
            }
        }
    }
    .box {
        --start: var(--sand-light);
        --stop: var(--sand);
        width: 21px;
        height: 21px;
        right: 100%;
        top: 21px;
        &:before,
        &:after {
            content: '';
            top: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
        &:before {
            height: 3px;
            margin-top: -1px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        }
        &:after {
            height: 1px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        }
    }
    &.animate {
        .default {
            --o: 0;
            transition-delay: 0s;
        }
        .success {
            --offset: 0;
            --o: 1;
            transition-delay: 7s;
            svg {
                transition-delay: 7.3s;
            }
        }
        .truck {
            animation: truck 10s ease forwards;
            &:before {
                animation: door1 2.4s ease forwards .3s;
            }
            &:after {
                animation: door2 2.4s ease forwards .6s;
            }
            .light {
                &:before,
                &:after {
                    animation: light 10s ease forwards;
                }
            }
        }
        .box {
            animation: box 10s ease forwards;
        }
        .lines {
            animation: lines 10s ease forwards;
        }
    }
}

@keyframes truck {
    10%,
    30% {
        transform: translateX(-164px);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translateX(-104px);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateX(-224px);
    }
    75%,
    100% {
        transform: translateX(24px);
    }
}

@keyframes lines {
    0%,
    30% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scaleY(.7) translateX(0);
    }
    35%,
    65% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    70% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scaleY(.7) translateX(-400px);
    }
}

@keyframes light {
    0%,
    30% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: perspective(2px) rotateY(-15deg) scaleX(.88);
    }
    40%,
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: perspective(2px) rotateY(-15deg) scaleX(.94);
    }
}

@keyframes door1 {
    30%,
    50% {
        transform: rotate(32deg);
    }
}

@keyframes door2 {
    30%,
    50% {
        transform: rotate(-32deg);
    }
}

@keyframes box {
    8%,
    10% {
        transform: translateX(40px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        transform: translateX(112px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    26% {
        transform: translateX(112px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    27%,
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

* {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    &:before,
    &:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
}

// Center & dribbble
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #E4ECFA;
    .dribbble {
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
        right: 20px;
        bottom: 20px;
        img {
            display: block;
            height: 28px;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
button(class='order')
  span(class='default') Complete Order
  span(class='success') Order Placed
    svg(viewbox='0 0 12 10')
      polyline(points='1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1')
  div(class='box')
  div(class='truck')
    div(class='back')
    div(class='front')
      div(class='window')
    div(class='light top')
    div(class='light bottom')
  div(class='lines')

<!-- dribbble -->
a(class='dribbble' href='https://dribbble.com/shots/7112021-Order-confirm-animation' target='_blank')
  img(src='https://cdn.dribbble.com/assets/dribbble-ball-mark-2bd45f09c2fb58dbbfb44766d5d1d07c5a12972d602ef8b32204d28fa3dda554.svg')
```

Can someone please help me???

Comment: It is not HTML...

Comment: Please fix the codepen link. This is some HTML preprocessor code not HTML (probably pug)

Comment: Looks like [Jade](https://jade-lang.com/), not HTML.

Comment: It looks to me like your missing a library, isn't function '$' from jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [Jade](https://jade-lang.com/), not HTML.  It's very easy to convert, just add arrow brackets and closing tags `div(class="whatever")` is `<div class="whatever"></div>`.  The indentations matter as they are what is considered "in" a tag

```
div(class="whatever")
  span hello
```

is

```
<div class="whatever">
  <span>hello</span>
</div>
```

The code in the CSS block is [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) a CSS preprocessor.

Comment: Or use any of the various jade to html converter sites, such as https://www.browserling.com/tools/jade-to-html

Comment: thanks man, but i have same problems with css, i know that codepen html code is named 'Pug', and css is named 'SCSS'

Comment: It’s SCSS, just like jade, you can find a online converter for that.